# Comparing entire response body in Postman, while it has JSON DataSchema

Tags: json, postman, web-api-testing

I'm quite new to Postman, and trying to create Automation Script to create an object that contains JSON Schema. But I'm getting an error which I'm not sure how to bypass.

Can you please help?

Here is my expected response script:

```
    pm.test("Body is correct", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.body("{\"Id\":"+typeId+",\"NamespaceId\":"+namespaceId+",\"Name\":\"Auto Test\",\"DataSchema\":\"\{\n    \"firstName\": {\n           \"type\": \"string\",\n           \"description\": \"The person\u0027s first name.\"\n    \}\n}\",\"Code\":\"AUTOTYPE\"}");
});
```

Here is the actual response (Body):

```
    {
    "Id": 1059,
    "NamespaceId": 1089,
    "Name": "Auto Test",
    "DataSchema": "{\r\n  \"firstName\": {\r\n    \"type\": \"string\",\r\n    \"description\": \"The person's first name.\"\r\n  }\r\n}",
    "Code": "AUTOTYPE"
}
```

Here is an error I'm getting:

```
Body is correct | AssertionError: expected response body to equal '{"Id":1059,"NamespaceId":1089,"Name":"Auto Test","DataSchema":"{\n "firstName": {\n "type": "string",\n "description": "The person\'s first name."\n }\n}","Code":"AUTOTYPE"}' but got '{"Id":1059,"NamespaceId":1089,"Name":"Auto Test","DataSchema":"{\\r\\n \\"firstName\\": {\\r\\n \\"type\\": \\"string\\",\\r\\n \\"description\\": \\"The person\\u0027s first name.\\"\\r\\n }\\r\\n}","Code":"AUTOTYPE"}'
```

Here is the actual part of create script:

```
    {  "NamespaceId": 1089,
  "Name": "Auto Test",
  "Code": "AUTOTYPE",
  "DataSchema": {
    "firstName": {
           "type": "string",
           "description": "The person's first name."
    }
}
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I tried to put more `\` but then Postman would complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you specify that you expect a string as a body, but than compare it to a JSON object. The way you've set it up now, the test is very brittle, more so than it needs to be IMHO.

A little more coding will give you a solution that is way more stable (e.g. doesn't depend on whitespace formatting, which is irrelevant to JSON):

```
pm.test("Body is correct", function () {
    const jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.Id)
        .to.be.a('number', 'Id should be a number')
        .that.is.equal(typeId, 'Id should equal typeId');
    pm.expect(jsonData.NamespaceId)
        .to.be.a('number', 'NamespaceId should be a number')
        .that.is.eql(namespaceId);
    pm.expect(jsonData.Name).to.equal("Auto Test");  

    // is this really what you want, i.e. should this be a string?
    pm.expect(jsonData.DataSchema).to.be.a('string'); 
    const dataSchema = JSON.parse(jsonData.DataSchema);
    pm.expect(dataSchema.firstName.type).to.equal("string");
    // ... etc    
});
```

Comment: Thanks Friso. I think this can work too (more work, but can pass with a lot of objects).

Comment: I find this useful. While it is more work to set it up, typing comes rather quickly to me and so the extra time is not so much. I run my scripts often, so finding out what (if anything) was wrong quickly saves me a lot of time. Getting the error that your string does not match the expected result is not really all that helpful. But YMMV

Comment: you could also use a JSON schema to test the structure and only than test the individual values. You'd end up with 5 lines like `pm.expect(jsonData.DataSchema.firstName.type).to.equal('string')`

Answer (score 0):

You have many spaces in your test. Try:

pm.response.to.have.body("{\"Id\":"+typeId+",\"NamespaceId\":"+namespaceId+",\"Name\":\"AutoTest\",\"DataSchema\":\"{\n"firstName\": {\n"type\": \"string\",\n"description\": \"The person\u0027s firstname.\"\n}\n}\",\"Code\":\"AUTOTYPE\"}");

Comment: For information about formatting, check out https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the feedback. I had to massage it a bit, and it finally works but seems to be only following specific pattern: 1) Make the test-data with no space at all in the DataSchema part (which is a JSON Schema of its own). 2) Then use following expected: pm.response.to.have.body("{\"Id\":"+typeId+",\"NamespaceId\":"+namespaceId+",\"Name\":\"Auto Test\",\"DataSchema\":\"{\\\"properties\\\":{\\\"firstName\\\":{\\\"type\\\": \\\"string\\\",\\\"description\\\": \\\"The person\\u0027s first name.\\\"}}}\",\"Code\":\"AUTOTYPE\"}");

Comment: Here is my new test-data _{"firstName":{"type": "string","description": "The person's first name."}}_  and I'm wondering if I still can use my original format??